# Getting Received fatal alert: close_notify error when I call web servide using JDK 7 but same web service works fine using JDK 6

Tags: openssl, java-7, java-6, sslhandshakeexception, oracle-soa

I am using SOA suite to connect to a web service using Oracle web logic server. 
I am able to connect to my external web service from SOA when I was having jdk 6.

After migrating to JDK 7 , I am not able to connect to same external web service and failing with below error.

Received fatal alert: close_notify

I have also checked error logs but I am not getting any extra information.

When I rollback to JDK 6 then it started working fine.

I included -Dweblogic.security.SSL.protocolVersion=ALL but it did not work in JDK 7.

I also performed openssl to my external web service and found below information.

```
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 787 bytes and written 311 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DES-CBC3-SHA
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DES-CBC3-SHA
    Session-ID: F7139DF3BD0F0AE0E06A2026C360EA84
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 714D9096E3110B0C7875F7340D7A156374B99FAA829AFE7E9E94E6A1F82DB9C3902080609FB8D887C6D056C2457037EC
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    Start Time: 1509622750
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
```

Could you please help me on that?

Comment: Look/ask if the server can provide any info on why it is rejecting your connection (easiest if it works). Otherwise if possible set sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl` on the JVM where you are attempting the connection, and capture stdout which will give a detailed trace of the protocol in postable (text) form. If you can't do that, get an external trace (wireshark tcpdump or similar), preferably filtered to only the relevant address/port, and put it somewhere like pastebin.